# how to read json data excel file in python

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, openpyxl

I have excel file in which json data column is present and I want to read each and every value of that column in pyspark python than how can I do that ?
[data.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QUNJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
from ast import literal_eval

import pandas as pd


df_raw = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
data_raw = df_raw.loc[:, "data"]

data_raw = data_raw.apply(literal_eval)
data_raw = data_raw.tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame(data_raw)
```

Basically, I use literal_eval to convert all the JSON strings in the "data" column to Python dicts, then I convert the list of Python dicts to a DataFrame.

Let me know if it works for you!

You can also use the `loads` function from the `json` package instead of `literal_eval`: `json.loads` is a bit more specific for the JSON format, whereas `literal_eval` is better if you have a generic dictionary or other Python data structures stored in the Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")

# Convert strings to dictionaries
df["data"] = df["data"].apply(json.loads)

# Explode dictionaries column into multiple columns
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df["data"].tolist())

# Join ID column with data columns
df = df[["id"]].join(df2)

print(df)
# Output:
#    id name languages
# 0   1  Bob   English
# 1   2  Bob   English
```